# Nginx убрать часть пути в try_files

Tags: php, nginx, php-nginx

Задача кажется базовой, но ответа быстро я найти не смог.

Итак, есть сайт, в которого всегда будет урл с дорисованным путём:

- site.com/aaa - индексная страница
- site.com/aaa/user/create
- site.com/aaa/blog/1

и т.д

и есть базовый конфиг nginx-а

```
    server { 
    listen 80; 
    server_name gym.loc; 

    # Путь к папке с кодом
    root /var/www/gym/;

    index index.php; 

    #location ~ \.xml$ {
    #   types { } default_type "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
        #}


    # Обработка php файлов с помощью fpm
    location ~ \.php$ { 
        try_files $uri =404; 
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock; 
    }
    }
```

при запросе `site.com/aaa` - nginx пытается найти `/var/www/gym/aaa/index.php`, мне же надо, чтобы он просто, классически шёл в `/var/www/gym/web/index.php`

как правильно должен выглядеть конфиг?

Comment: https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias

Answer (score 0):

Не увидел у вас базового конфига. Куда вдруг пропала обработка корневых запросов?

```
location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
      ...
}
```